# Orweb copy page url

Tags: orweb

I am running orweb/ orbot on a Sony Xperia z2.

I can't find out how to copy / paste a page url.

Is this possible?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, thus I'll close it. If you have further information, please [edit](https://tor.stackexchange.com/posts/3674/edit) the question and it can be reopened.